# Set Active tab on ajax response

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Trying to set active tab after ajax response

> ```
>   if (data.length == 0)
>   {         
>      Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#itemIdTabPanel')[0].items.items[0].activeTab.set(true);
>   }
> ```

I have keep toggle the tab based on ajax response data. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the active tab via index directly on the tabpanel, not on the tab itself:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel')[0].setActiveTab(1);
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a4v

Comment: Thank you sir for your help